# Black hole gravity at bottom (deepest end)

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes

If black holes are hole in space and time then at bottom or below bottom there is no more gravity of black hole.
As any hole has an end (Deepest end).
Is this true ?

******** **EDIT** ***********

http://www.nasa.gov/audience/forstudents/k-4/stories/nasa-knows/what-is-a-black-hole-k4.html

> A black hole is a place in space where gravity pulls so much that even light can not get out. The gravity is so strong because matter has been **squeezed into a tiny space**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole

> A black hole is a region of spacetime exhibiting such strong gravitational effects that nothing—including particles and electromagnetic radiation such as light—can escape from inside it.[1] The theory of general relativity predicts that a sufficiently compact mass can **deform spacetime** to form a black hole

As black hole **squeezed** or create **pit** or **deform spacetime** in space time fabric. So at an end of that pit there is no more gravity.

So my question is, is this true?

Comment: Downvoting as it's unclear what you're asking. Perhaps you can clarify what you mean by "the bottom".

Comment: bottom means end of black hole at deepest. End of black hole

Comment: I suspect that you have a reasonably serious misconception of what a black hole is, which is why your question is difficult to answer. I suggest first reading here: http://www.cosmos4kids.com/files/stars_blackholes.html and then deciding whether to reform your question if it still stands

Comment: A black hole is a dense point that band the space such as a sink hole in a lake for example. Due to this any nearby object does not escape from it.

Comment: The analogy with the sinkhole in the lake has a serious flaw. Please see the link above for further info! :)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/13839/2451

Comment: This questions isn't unclear. The question itself is very clear once you see the flawed analogy it is based on. I nominate it for re-opening on that basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The holes you are used to seeing most likely occur on Earth. Since Earth's surface is a 2-dimensional object, holes in it are also 2-dimensional. Given that we live in a 3-dimensional world (spatially/geometrically), these holes would then be traversable; leading to a "pit" below. Since it isn't realistic to have a pit that goes completely through Earth, you would then be used to those which have bottoms and nothing below.

The problem with using holes that you are used to as an analogy to a black hole is that black holes exist in 3-dimensional space instead of a 2-dimensional surface. As such, they are spherical; you can enter the black hole from any direction. Given that there are only 3 spatial dimensions, there is no "black pit" with a bottom. That is, below a black hole is exactly the same as above a black hole. This is good because in space there really is no way to define "above" or "below".

A black hole is simply an extremely massive object. It is not a literal 2D hole in space.