# Inside a black hole can a person ‘touch’ space?

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, metric-tensor, curvature, event-horizon

Take a look at this picture

[image]

Now if a person falls inside a black hole and he stretches his arms outside. At some point the region which is red in colour will exactly match the width of the person who has stretched his arms out. At that time will he be able to touch space out there?

( PS - I am a high school student. So if possible please don’t give complicated answers. )

Comment: That's not "Width", that's a 2 dimensional representation of a bottomless gravity well.    It's an indication of direction, a bit like, if you're standing on the North Pole, every step you take is south.  Inside the event horizon of a black hole, every direction is toward the center.    There is no moving away from the center.   That's what the diagram represents.    That and, when are we not touching space?

Comment: Possible related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/13839/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It seems to me the question is pretty clear with a straight-forward answer, so I'm not sure where these close votes as *unclear* are coming from.

Answer (score 6):

This is an [embedding diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding). It illustrates the curvature of a 2D manifold by embedding it in a manifold of higher dimensionality - in this case 3D.

But this is just an illustration. The extra dimension doesn't exist in general relativity. Instead the curvature of the manifold is [intrinsic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntrinsicCurvature.html). Because the extra dimension doesn't exist occupants of the universe cannot move into it, so in the diagram you show the observers are confined to the sheet and cannot move out of it into the third dimension. An observer falling into the black hole follows the trajectory within the sheet I've shown in red:

[image: Trajectory]

So it isn't possible to move out of the sheet to the middle of the throat and then stretch out your arms to toch the sheet at either side, because the throat doesn't actally exist.